# Should I have a table column with total price?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Scheme:

```
create table dbo.Baskets ( 
  Id int not null primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)

create table dbo.Products ( 
  Id int not null primary key clustered (Id),
  BasketId int not null,
  Price decimal (10, 2) not null,
 Name nvarchar (80) not null
)
```

So one basket can have many products.

I often need to find baskets in a specific price range.

I know the basket price is the sum of its products prices.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Should I add a column to Baskets with TotalPrice?
2. Would this improve query performance a lot?
3. Can this be done automatically when Products are updated?
4. Should I index some column here?

Comment: Caching aggregate values is a valid optimization strategy, yes. The cost is increased efforts on keeping them current.

Comment: That is why I asked if that was an automatic way to update the basket total price when a product is updated.

Comment: use `trigger` to update it

Comment: it would depends on your runtime selecting how many records, and will the calculation logic change from time to time due to new business logic added in or not, like tax rate or etc

Comment: I will have not more than 80 baskets. Each basket will have only 4 to 6 products ... And the only calculation I am making is summing the prices not more. The most common query is: "Get a random basket with total price between 200 and 400".

Comment: When it comes to performance, it's always a good idea to specify the product you are working with. You cannot (should not) expect that every suggestion on performance improvement applies to every RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion, and I might actually get a lot of hate for this, but this sounds like a clear case of premature optimisation.

Is the `JOIN` required to compute the total cost of a basket a bottleneck?
If not, any effort you're spending here rather than optimising actual bottlenecks is ill-spent. If it takes, say, 1% of the whole process, but you speed it up by 100%, your process is going to go 1% faster.
If, on the other hand, you find some other part of the process takes 90% of the time and you speed it up by 10%, you've made your process 9% faster.

If this `JOIN` *is* a bottleneck, or at least slow enough that it impacts user experience, you have to weight the pros and cons.

- Pros: it's faster.
- Cons: you have to do a significant amount of work maintaining duplicated information in your database.

This con is, to me, rather large. From experience, on most real life projects, duplicating information in database is going to cause bugs - there *will* be a time when some refactoring, unforeseen / untested for edge case, tired co-worker fixing another issue, .... is going to cause your production service not to update the total price of the basket correctly, and you will display incorrect information to your end-user.

You just need to decide whether a rare incorrect total basket price (possibly never, more likely very rarely but still happening) is acceptable for the performance increase.

If you've not quantified that performance increase yet, why are we having this discussion? You're talking about duplicating database information (a BAD THING) because it might bring unknown and possibly null benefits.

Answer (score 0):

1. Having Total on Order is a common practice.
2. It will, as you don't have to calculate it on the fly which requires `INNER JOIN` and aggregation. If you list orders often in UI, you can display total without recalculating it.
3. This can be done with a trigger.
4. You can add an index, if you use that field often in WHERE clause.

Best solution in early stage will be to isolate your implementation from application by using a view for orders where total amount and other aggregated fields will be available. Once you hit the performance problem, you can add calculated field without affecting your code.

If you database allows window functions calculate total as:

`SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID) AS TotalAmount`

Answer (score 0):

As always...it all depends.

Pros of adding a calculated column (TotalPrice)
No need to recalculate every time especially if doing a retrieve based on totalPrice (less CPU time but more disk space and retrieval effort)

Cons
Possibility of introducing an error if another field changes such as price of one item. or if you decide to add another column such as qty, or discount.

The best way to determine which is the right way forward is to test.  One way is to normalise everything, that is not have a total price, and take metrics, and then after some time add the totla price as an optimisation and take further metrics and see if there is an improvement.

Same with the indexes although columns that you are doing a search on should be indexed.

Hope this helps